# Empty "notify" file being created on external hard drive

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive

I recently attached a 1TB USB external hard drive to my Windows 7 Home Premium desktop. I noticed that some program is creating a file on the root of the hard drive called "notify". If I delete the file, it comes back within a few hours. Does anyone know what software could be creating this file?

[image: Explorer screenshot]

[image: Properties screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what could be creating it, but I would use [SysInternals Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to answer that question.  It's a piece of Microsoft software which allows you to monitor many things, but in this case you could set up a file filter.

When you first start the program, it pops up a Process Monitor Filter dialog box.  Select `Path` from the first dropdown, and then the path to the file (e.g. `e:\notify`) as the value of the filter, and then hit the `Add` button and click `OK`.  Then let it run until the file appears.  Once the file appears, Process Monitor should show you which process is creating it.

Comment: Thanks. I will try it and see what Process Monitor tells me.

Comment: @bdr9 Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: @Hans No, I was not able to figure it out. I tried Process Monitor but I wasn't able to capture the program that created the file. Are you having the same problem?

Comment: @bdr9 Yep. I found this thread but there's no definitive answer: http://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/1e8app/a_0kb_file_called_notify_with_no_file_extension/